# Play! Framework loading yaml from test sub package

Tags: java, playframework

I have a yaml file loaded by BasicTest.java in the test package, this creates the db data as expected in the h2 in memory db.  When I move the BasicTest.java into a sub package, e.g. test.unit, it does not work.  The yaml file is found, but the data is not created.  What needs to change to fix this?

My test setup is shown below.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Could you provide console output?

Comment: The console output is the standard fare, i.e.  connected to jdbc:h2:mem....,

Comment: woops, wasn't quite finished there.  So the console output is Listening for HTTP on port 9000, Connected to jdbc:h2:mem, Application now started etc.  I am using a schema, so I have this in my application.conf:  %test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA.  As said before this works seamlessly when I have BasicTest.java in the default package under test, when I move it into a sub package the table is created but not populated.  In both cases it is finding the data.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path to your "yml" to play framework internal PATH before you try to load it. Example(path to file is relative to application path):

```
VirtualFile appRoot = VirtualFile.open(Play.applicationPath);
Play.javaPath.add(0, appRoot.child("test/sub/packages/data.yml"));
```

Comment: Thanks, however I still face the same issue when using your suggestion.

Comment: i made a mistake: path should be relative to application root: like  `test/some/packages/data.yml` for myapp/test/some/packages/data.yml. Have you tried this way ?

Comment: I have tried the following - Play.javaPath.add(0, appRoot.child("test/data.yml"));  The class that is not working is located under myApp/test/unit/myclass.  data.yml is located at myApp/test/data.yml.